# Why some structs inherit interfaces, but do not implement all of their members?

Tags: c#, inheritance, struct, interface, .net-core

While programming in .NET Core I stumbled upon a struct called [`StringValues`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.primitives.stringvalues). It comes from the `Microsoft.Extensions.Primitive` assembly and its saved under the same namespace. Its source code is available on [GitHub](https://github.com/aspnet/Extensions/blob/master/src/Primitives/src/StringValues.cs).

I noticed that it inherits from a few interfaces:

- `IList<string>`
- `ICollection<string>`
- `IEnumerable<string>`
- `IEnumerable`
- `IReadOnlyList<string>`
- `IReadOnlyCollection<string>`
- `IEquatable<StringValues>`
- `IEquatable<string>`
- `IEquatable<string[]>`

That's quite a lot for a struct, I'd say. As I were looking through its methods (in Visual Studio definition viewer) I noticed how strangely few it does provide. For example, I didn't see basic [`ICollection<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.icollection-1) methods which are [`Add()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.icollection-1.add), [`Clear()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.icollection-1.clear) or [`Remove()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.icollection-1.remove).

When I tried to explicity cast an instance of `StringValues` to `ICollection<string>` and use `Add()`:

```
var stringValues = new StringValues("Foo");
var stringCollection = stringValues as ICollection<string>;
stringCollection.Add("Bar");
```

I ended up with `NotSupportedException` thrown at `Add()` method call:

> NotSupportedException: Specified method is not supported.

So I did a journey to the source code (the invaluable advantages of open-source) to see what's going on! And then I saw:

```
void ICollection<string>.Add(string item)
{
    throw new NotSupportedException();
}

void IList<string>.Insert(int index, string item)
{
    throw new NotSupportedException();
}

bool ICollection<string>.Remove(string item)
{
    throw new NotSupportedException();
}

void IList<string>.RemoveAt(int index)
{
    throw new NotSupportedException();
}

void ICollection<string>.Clear()
{
    throw new NotSupportedException();
}
```

#### Question

What's the point of such programming manner? I always though that, by inheriting from an interface, I'm declaring that particular type can be used on par with the inherited interface.

In this case it seems like this struct wasn't meant to be used in public? That kind of feeling I get while looking at implemented `Contains()` method but still  marked as internal:

```
bool ICollection<string>.Contains(string item)
{
    return IndexOf(item) >= 0;
}
```

Comment: It seems as if it's intended to be immutable. [Immutable data structures offer certain advantages](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/mt795189.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396).

Comment: Seems like a violation of [Listkovs Subst Prinziple](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle)?

Comment: `ICollection` historically covers both mutable and immutable types, through `IsReadOnly`. This can be considered a design flaw, but if it is it's not one introduced by `StringValues`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because it is often *useful to do so*, as long as the caller only calls the available methods. They can check things like `IList.IsReadOnly` to anticipate this - if that returns `false`, they should know not to expect `Add` etc to work.

It can be useful to pass a structurally immutable type to something that takes an API that historically takes a mutable API, such as `IList`, because that same interface *also provides other useful functionality*.

Similarly, `Stream` has things like `CanRead` and `CanWrite`, and if either returns `false`, you can expect the corresponding read/write APIs to fail.

Comment: Plus the struct is declared `public readonly struct StringValues`, so having a `.Add`, `Remove`, or `Clear` seems counter-intuitive.

Comment: @ron-beyer Sadly the `readonly` keyword is not present in `StringValues` definition when looking from Visual Studio definition viewer. When I was looking at the source code I focused on the methods body and I didn't notice it was there. New lesson learned.